# MySQL: Delete a record from all tables in one shot

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database, with one table that has a primary key, `f_id` that is referenced in multiple table as a foreign key.

I want to delete all records where `f_id` is a specific value from all referenced tables in a single batch.

I am attempting to delete a specific `f_id` record in the primary table, however I cannot since there are records present in the referenced tables containing that `f_id` value.

How can I delete all related records at once without having to hand-write a query for each and every related table?

Comment: Are all tables InnoDB or MyISAM ???

Comment: all the tables are InnoDB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automated way of doing so is by defining [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on your tables, with a `DELETE CASCADE` in your case. This way, a `DELETE` on the master table will propagate and delete matching rows from all derived tables.

You will have to use `InnoDB` tables for that.

I assume your tables do not have foreign keys at the moment, otherwise you wouldn't ask. In which case you may try using triggers, see [this post](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/triggers-use-case-compilation-part-i) for an example. Triggers are bad for performance, mind you.

Those who do not define foreign keys tend to work out all `DELETE`s in application code.